# How to immediately remove Testflight external beta user's access to build?

Tags: testflight

If I delete an external beta user from Testflight (via iTunes Connect), would he/she still have access to the build for the rest of the beta period (the rest of the 60 days)? Is there any way to immediately revoke access for an external user? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is not. Once the app is downloaded and installed it can't be remotely removed or disabled. At least not through TestFlight mechanisms... you could do it through an account based system in your app instead.